# Compile Dust template on server side

Tags: java, server-side, playframework-1.x, dust.js

I want to compile dust.js template on server for some cases, but i don't have any idea about it. On server use Play framework + Java, so how to compile dust template on server? anybody have ideas ?? please help me solve this problem. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get a JavaScript interpreter to compile dust.js templates on the server. You can do it either using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) or [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rhino) or using [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) included in the JDK.
Also refer [Scripting: Compiling Scripts in Java 6](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t87870.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grunt for running build tasks, then you could compile your dust templates on the fly with the dust compiler plugin (below):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-dust-compiler